# Google groundOverlay Skew?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay, skew

I am using the Google Maps API to add some overlays to the map. I'm not having any trouble actually adding the overlays where I want since I found this nifty jsfiddle to determine corners on a map:  http://jsfiddle.net/4cWCW/3/

But I discovered that Google skews some of the image overlays, specifically ones that are more north or south. This makes sense since a map is a 2D projection of a globe and some skewing happens, but I don't want google impose this on my overlays. **I am wondering if there is any way to correct for this?**

overlay method(javascript):

```
var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(42, 27.9),
    new google.maps.LatLng(80, -168.6));

var tempOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("ru2.png", imageBounds);
tempOverlay.setMap(map);
```

Specifically here, I have a silhouette of Russia I want to place on the map, but it stretches the top of the image without changing the lower part of it, so I can't actually line it up with the county location.

Comment: Have you looked at [ProjectedOverlay](http://www.usnaviguide.com/v3maps/ProjectedOverlayTest.htm)?

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing since google just calls it "custom" overlays. Thanks for the suggestion!